# Is function declaration in Go strict?

Tags: go

Why does this code work? The function `Introduce()` accepts a pointer to `Person` but when we create `p`, it is an object (not a pointer).
So is function declaration not strict?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Person struct {
    Name string
}

func (p *Person) Introduce() {
    fmt.Printf("Hi, I'm %s\n", p.Name)
}

func main() {
    p := Person{Name: "Fedya"}
    fmt.Println(p)
    p.Introduce()

    p1 := &Person{Name: "Fedya"}
    fmt.Println(p1)
    p1.Introduce()
}
```

Comment: "Strict" is not an attribute defined in the language spec. So asking whether something is strict or not is not a well defined question. Read about method sets.

Answer (score 4):

[Per the specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets):

> The method set of any other type T consists of all methods declared with receiver type T. The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods declared with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method set of T).

Comment: well, if `*T` contains the method set of `T` (and vice versa), then why do we need to declare in function `*` (asterics)? In any case it will work, will it?

Comment: Receiving a pointer instead of a value changes the behavior of the method (e.g. a setter could only work with a pointer receiver). Also, your assumption that it's "and vice versa" is false and does not come from the spec. In cases where the compiler is able to auto-address a value in order to invoke a method with a pointer receiver, the compiler will do so, but not all values are addressable (e.g. a value stored in a map).

Answer (score 4):

Go `func`s that accept an object *receiver* (enclosed in parentheses) must not be confused with class methods which are common in OOP languages. Whether you define your instance as a pointer or not, when the *receiver* is a pointer, Go will pass your instance as a pointer to the `func`.

P.S. You can even call that `func` with a `nil` receiver as:

```
var p *Persion  // p == nil
p.Introduce()   // Compiler: OK!
```

Comment: then it doesn't mater is the object receiver in the function a pointer or not, - Go will pass our instance in anycase and it will work... so why then we need at all use an asterics in the function declaration?

Comment: @rozerro A pointer receiver does change the behavior of the `func`. Note that when you define a non-pointer receiver, Go passes the object _by value_ to the `func`, i.e. if you make any changes to the receiver, the actual passed object won't take effect of the changes.